# How to read an xml file from R.java

Tags: android, xml

I have an xml file inside the res folder under the xml forlder. I want to parse it with SAX. I know there are lots of example but I want to understand InputStream, InputSource, File deeply. I can reach the file writing `R.xml.hippo` (hippo is the name of the xml file).

But how can I give this resource as a stream?
I know when I write `R.xml.hippo` to anywhere it will be reference(int) but I want give it as a source. What is and how converting an int to starting point of stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the file inside the `raw` folder. Then you can access it via `Resources.openRawResource()`. For more information refer to [Android Developer's page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can read XML from `assets` folder as well as from `res/raw` folder.

**To read from assets folder**

```
AssetManager manager = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = manager.open("your_xml.xml");
```

**To read from raw folder**

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.your_xml);
```

And `parse` this `inputStream` to your XML Parser.

Comment: Very clear explanation. thank you for getAssets() even if it isn't my question. But I've learnt.